# Определить тип объекта File по его дескриптору Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, native

Как известно, за дескриптором типа `File` в Windows может скрываться сразу несколько типов объектов: файлы, директории, каналы (pipes), консоли, почтовые ящики (mailslots). А каким образом, имея на руках только дескриптор можно отличать их друг от друга?

С разделением на файлы / директории вроде понятно: через `NtQueryInformationFile` запрашиваем `FileStandardInformation`, а там есть булево поле `Directory`. (Мне желателен Native API, но это не обязательно)

Но что делать с остальными? Парсить имя выглядит довольно плохой затеей. По идее, можно скармливать их функциям, специфичным к типу, и смотреть на возвращаемые коды ошибки (вроде `STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH`), но хотелось бы найти более универсальный подход, не использующий «метод тыка». Есть идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует функция [GetFileType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364960(v=vs.85).aspx), которая позволяет различить тип в пределах трех групп:

`FILE_TYPE_CHAR` - порт COM/LPT или консоль

`FILE_TYPE_DISK` - файл, директория, дисковый том или физический диск

`FILE_TYPE_PIPE` - канал или сокет

Затрудняюсь пока сказать, куда падают mailslots.

Чтобы различить между файлами, директориями и прочими объектами из той же группы, нужно использовать функцию [GetFileInformationByHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952(v=vs.85).aspx). Для директории установлен атрибут `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`, для файла он снят, для прочих - функция вернет ошибку.

Что касается остальных двух групп, видимо можно различить только вызовом функций, специфичных для этого типа объекта.

Comment: Спасибо, этого вполне хватит. Для тех, кому интересна реализация в Native API: это делается через `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` (см. [reactos](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/fd3a6c1089f8eb315bf1ab1dea85b44894938a05/dll/win32/kernel32/client/file/fileinfo.c#L419-L474))